# Flutter app containing a 3rd party framework runs on iOS simulator from within Xcode, but not when using Flutter's run command from the shell

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, ios-simulator

I have a problem getting a Flutter app to run on the iOS simulator. The app uses a third party framework, which is included from within Xcode (`Runner -> General Tab -> Targets -> Runner -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content`)

[image: how the framework was included in the project]

When I run the app from within Xcode, it builds and deploys on real hardware AND on the simulator successfully. However, when I build and run the app from the command line using `flutter run`, it builds and runs on real hardware, but fails to run on the simulator.

```sh
ld: warning: ignoring file
    /Users/XXXX/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/ConnectSDK.framework/ConnectSDK, missing required
    architecture arm64 in file /XXXX/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/ConnectSDK.framework/ConnectSDK
    (2 slices)
    Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PGPeripheral", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PGCentralManager", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: '/Users/XXXX/ios/ConnectSDK/ConnectSDK.xcframework' is missing architecture(s) required by this
    target (arm64), but may still be link-compatible. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    note: '/Users/XXXX/ios/ConnectSDK/ConnectSDK.xcframework' is missing architecture(s) required by this
    target (arm64), but may still be link-compatible. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

Why does it work on simulators when I run it from Xcode? Does Flutter run simulators with a different architecture?

The 3rd party framework includes the following slices

[image: Slices provided by the framework]